# Is there any meaning difference in the pair "festlegen" versus "vereinbaren"?

Tags: word-usage

I would kindly ask to compare the meaning of "festlegen" versus "vereinbaren". Do they mean pretty much the same or is there any significant contextual difference?

Comment: Welcome. There are differences, they don't mean the same, like define/agree don't mean the same. Did you look them up in a dictionary, e.g. www.duden.de or www.dwds.com, or a translating dictionary like www.leo.org ? What exactly seems to be unclear ?

Comment: Without adding  specifics (as commented by a_donda) this question is likely to be closed, since it can be answered by a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/festlegen) and [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vereinbaren) the definitions differ quite greatly.

"Festlegen" does **not** refer - in contrast to "vereinbaren" - to a jointly developed statement/deadline/date/etc.

The date of an exam is set (note that "to set" is one meaning of "festlegen") and announced by the university. Normally it does not include any negotiations or agreements with the students.

In contrast, a movie night date can be arranged and agreed upon (note the definition by wiktionary analog to "vereinbaren") by a group of friends. One person does not set the date, but all together.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. I asked because in the Polish-German dictionary the Polish equivalent word I found, are with very similar contextual meaning in my understanding (generally - action of getting decided about something).
So following your example: some people might had to first "vereinbaren" the date of an exam, before they "festlegen" it (or "legen it fest") and announce it.

Comment: @Przemek It would be a goog idea to explain that in your question (next time) :)